# Trying to split a char* in C++ using strok,program compiles but crashes

Tags: c++, string, char

So i am trying to split a char* in C++ like this:

```
char* writable = &buffer[0u];
char* test;
test = strtok (writable," ,.-");
while (test != NULL)
        {
                test = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
        }
```

The buffer that is used is a string that i got from reading a file.
As  you can see the delimiter i use is space.
While this compiles, it crashes immediately.
But when i tried this:

```
        test = strtok (writable," ,.-");        
        test = strtok (NULL," ,.-");        
        test = strtok (NULL," ,.-");        
        test = strtok (NULL," ,.-");        
        test = strtok (NULL," ,.-");
        test = strtok (NULL," ,.-");
```

It compilied and worked just fine.

All output (char* test) is written in to a file to confirm what is working and what not.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What is the contents of buffer?  How many times does the while loop execute before it crashes?   And is buffer really writable? (note that strtok modifies the contents of what it parses)

Comment: The while loop crashes before it even is executed.The contents of buffer are numbers(i am parsing a pgm file).The buffer has the whole file in it.Yes writable gets the correct value from buffer.

Comment: The only thing that is executed is the first call of the strtok function.After that it crashes.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything in the code that you show that would cause it to crash, so the answer  must involve things that are not shown.  Generally you want to provide this question in the form of a complete mini program. (including example input)  Which may involve just a few additional lines of code.

Comment: Yes sorry for the bad way of expressing my question, i should have given the whole program.Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: "Trying to split a char* in C++ using strok,program compiles but crashes" - seldom does a title alone say so much and already contain the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `strtok()` in C++ code -- it *modifies* the argument string. (What you have done is create a pointer to the beginning of your `buffer[]`, so it still modifies your buffer.)

Instead, use an algorithm along these lines:

```
string s = "string, to, split";
string delimiters = " ,";
size_t current;
size_t next = -1;
do
{
  current = next + 1;
  next = s.find_first_of( delimiters, current );
  cout << s.substr( current, next - current ) << endl;
}
while (next != string::npos);
```

If you must use `strtok()`, make sure to make an actual copy of your source string first. A `std::vector<char>` comes in handy here:

```
std::vector <char> scopy( s.begin(), s.end() );
auto p = std::strtok( scopy.data(), ... );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to that, it is not reentrant. (Which causes the thread problems too.)

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> The buffer that is used is a string that i got from reading a file

My psychic powers kick in and tell me that you may have forgotten to null terminate "buffer" with a trailing null char to force a proper string termination. You should definitely investigate if that's the case as that could be the cause of your crash.

Also, this line:

```
char* writable = &buffer[0u];
```

At first, it looked suspicious to me, but then I realized it's ok.  But in any case, this is better form:

```
char* writable = buffer;
```

Also, if buffer is pointing to or is a hardcoded literal string, e.g. `buffer = "Some hard coded string";`), the the strtok is sure to crash as it tries to write to that address.